# Probleme with PPA and Ubuntu distro

Tags: updates, ppa

I use Ubuntu 14.04 64bit. I'd like to install the following applications:

- Final Term
- Ledger

But I can't, because, after having installed the corresponding PPA for [Ledger](https://launchpad.net/%7Embudde/+archive/ledger) and [Final Term](https://launchpad.net/%7Efinalterm/+archive/daily), I do `sudo apt-get update` and I get the following messages:

> `W: Impossible de récupérer http://ppa.launchpad.net/finalterm/daily/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found`
>
> `W: Impossible de récupérer http://ppa.launchpad.net/finalterm/daily/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found`
>
> `W: Impossible de récupérer http://ppa.launchpad.net/mbudde/ledger/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found`
>
> `W: Impossible de récupérer http://ppa.launchpad.net/mbudde/ledger/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found`

I could be wrong, but it seems that Ubuntu looks for packages in places that don't exist, beacuse both PPA mention saucy as the last distro, and I use trusty. Is this related?

Is there a way to install these apps?*

*<sub>without building them, I prefer automatic updates</sub>

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

There are no packages for the current ubuntu release you use, you should contact with the authors or those PPA's.

Also notice that Ubuntu 14.04 was recently released and it may take time for the repository authors (if they plan to) to build packages for it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Maybe you could explain me why the repository authors need to build packages of the same app for every ubuntu update, I don't see the logic of it (but I'm a newbee with Linux)